# How to retrive userID from users table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a two table named **users** and **profile** . In **profile** table there is a column named userID.Now i want to this `userID` column takes value from **users** table's `id`.I have done database relationships part.But can not retrieve data with view.I have searched but i have not found any satisfying answer according my issue.

By the way i am new in Laravel.I have tried so far

**User Model:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table ="users";
    protected $fillable = [
        'userName', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function userProfile(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
    }
}
```

**Profile Model:**

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = "profiles";
    public $fillable = ["firstName","lastName","middleName","DOB","gender","featuredProfile","email","phone","summary","profilePic"];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
   }
}
```

And i am trying to retrieve `userID` with `{{$profile->userID}}`.I really don't know where is the problem and how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

you will need to tell laravel to get the relationship model like this

```
$profile = Profile::find(1);
$userID  = $profile->user->id;
```

---

edit:
from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

> model is automatically assumed to have a user_id foreign key.

which in your case is `userId` so change your `hasOne` and `belongsTo` methods to tell laravel the name of `foreign_key` you are using

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile', 'userId');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'userId');
}
```

Comment: Its giving me an error `Trying to get property of non-object`.

Comment: `$profile->user->id;` because db column of `user` table is `id` instead of `Userid`

Answer (score 0):

Please add userID to the fillable array of profiles.

Please check below sample code to do the same.

```
public $fillable = ["firstName","lastName","middleName","DOB","gender","featuredProfile","email","phone","summary","profilePic","userID"];
```

Comment: This is not necessary at all. It even has security risks. Since he uses something else than user_id he just has to tell laravel what the name of the id on the users table is.